# How to save flutter table calendar events once added

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter programming, and I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvaKVud0Jx0) tutorial to set up the table calendar to allow users to add their own events.  However, when I go to a different page in my app or hot restart the app, the events on the calendar don't save.  Does anyone know how to make sure that the events don't disappear?  Thank you!

Code:

```
class CalendarRoute extends StatefulWidget{
@override
_CalendarRouteState createState() => _CalendarRouteState();
}

 class _CalendarRouteState extends State<CalendarRoute> {
 CalendarFormat format = CalendarFormat.month;
 DateTime selectedDay = date;
 DateTime focusedDay = date;
 late Map <DateTime,List<Event>> selectedEvents;
 TextEditingController _eventController = TextEditingController();
 @override
 void initState(){
   selectedEvents = {};
   super.initState();
 }

 List<Event> _getEventsFromDay(DateTime date){
   return selectedEvents[date]??[];
 }
 void dispose(){
  _eventController.dispose();
 super.dispose();
 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text("Calendar",
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow)),
     backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
  ),
  body:
      Column(
   children:[
  TableCalendar(
    firstDay: DateTime.utc(2021,6,8),
    lastDay: DateTime.utc(2022,6,8),
    focusedDay: focusedDay,
    calendarFormat: format,
    onFormatChanged: (CalendarFormat _format){
      setState((){
        format = _format;
      });
      },
    startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
    onDaySelected: (DateTime selectDay, DateTime focusDay){
      setState((){
        selectedDay = selectDay;
        focusedDay = focusDay;
      });
    },
      selectedDayPredicate: (DateTime day){
        return isSameDay(selectedDay, day);
      },

      eventLoader:_getEventsFromDay,
    calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
      isTodayHighlighted: true,
          selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.yellow,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          ),
      selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.brown,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      )
  ),
    headerStyle:HeaderStyle(
      formatButtonVisible: true,
      titleCentered: true,
      formatButtonShowsNext: false,
      formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.brown,

      ),
        formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow)
    )

  ),
  ..._getEventsFromDay(selectedDay).map((Event event)=> ListTile(title:Text(event.title))),
]),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: ()=>showDialog(context:context, builder: (context)=>AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Add event"),
      content: TextFormField(
        controller:_eventController,

      ),
      actions: [TextButton(
        child: Text("Cancel"),
        onPressed:() =>Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Ok"),
          onPressed:() {
            if(_eventController.text.isEmpty){

            }
            else if (selectedEvents[selectedDay]!=null){
              selectedEvents[selectedDay]!.add(
                Event(title: _eventController.text),);
            }
            else{
              selectedEvents[selectedDay] = [Event(
              title: _eventController.text
              )
              ];
            }
            _eventController.clear();
            Navigator.pop(context);
            setState((){});
            return;
          }
        ),]
    )),
  label: Text("Add event"),
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `shared_preferences`

Link to [pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

[More info here On Flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value)